# Gtk2 gui looks different after compiling with py2exe to make a exe file

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, windows-7, py2exe, gtk2

This is how it look when is run the scripts directly
the script is an example form https://zetcode.com/gui/pygtk/layout/

[directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3tQt.png)

py2exe run fine and make the exe file but it looks like this
Kinldy if someone tell me that is causing this.

[form exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lum9Z.png)

Comment: Hi got the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884959/bundling-gtk-resources-with-py2exe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bundling GTK resources with py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884959/bundling-gtk-resources-with-py2exe)